# Get channel to split in web request

Tags: python, string, opencv

I have a web request that can get string parameters as (I'm simplifying the code to show the challenging part):

```
ch1 = "RGB" # or "HSV"

sing1 = "G" # or "V"
```

I also get an image from the request and I want to perform a color conversion and a split according to the previous variables, for this I take the variable `ch1` and looped on it trying to find if `sing1` is in it, if yes the index is the channel to split:

```
for i in range(0, len(ch1)):
                    if ch1[i] == sing1:
                        decoded_image = cv2.split(decoded_image)[i]
                        break
```

This works but seems pretty wrong. I thought on doing a `dir` with all possible colorSpace/channel combinations but that also seems wrong.

Is there a more proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary to map the char to an int.

```
colorDic={
   "R":0,
   "G":1,
   "B":2,
   "H":0,
   "S":1,
   "V":2
}
index= colorDic[sing1]
decoded_image = cv2.split(decoded_image)[index]
```